# Android session variable does not work in PHP file

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am using Android Studio for developing an Android app. My work is to store some data in MySQL using session variables created in Android.

My android code works fine. But in PHP, session variable does not store in php variable. I tried, but no use.

I attached my coding:

**MainActivity.class**

```
   Location location = 
locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (location != null) {
            double latti = location.getLatitude();
            double longi = location.getLongitude();
            lattitude = String.valueOf(latti);
            longitude = String.valueOf(longi);

            EditText.setText(lattitude);
            EditText1.setText(longitude);

            String fullName = EditText.getText().toString();
            String userName = EditText1.getText().toString();
           String user=txtUser3.getText().toString();//this is actually my 
        session variable created in another class file
       String fam=fid.getText().toString();//another session variable..
   //the following two toasts is to check that session variables stores or 
       not..but it works..
             Toast.makeText(this,user,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(this,fam,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           new Signin(this).execute(fullName, userName, user, fam );//here i 
   pass four variables including session variable

        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Unable to Trace your 
      location",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

This is another class **Signin.java**

```
    class Signin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

  private Context context;

  public Signin(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
   }

   protected void onPreExecute() {

  }

 @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    String fullName = arg0[0];
    String userName = arg0[1];
    String user = arg0[2];
    String fam = arg0[3];


    String link;
    String data;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    String result;

    try {
        data = "?fullname=" + URLEncoder.encode(fullName, "UTF-8");
        data += "&username=" + URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8");
        data += "&user=" + URLEncoder.encode(user, "UTF-8");
        data += "&fam=" + URLEncoder.encode(fam, "UTF-8");


        // link = "http://192.168.0.7/Signup.php" + data;
        link= "https://19891be3.ngrok.io/Signup.php"+data;
        URL url = new URL(link);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        result = bufferedReader.readLine();
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
   }

   @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    String jsonStr = result;
    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            String query_result = jsonObj.getString("query_result");
            if (query_result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                 Toast.makeText(context, "Data inserted successfully. Signup 
     successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (query_result.equals("FAILURE")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Data could not be inserted. Signup 
       failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't connect to remote 
      database.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error parsing JSON data.", 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't get any JSON data.", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
      }
    }
```

This is my php file

```
   <?php
     $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","tracker");
      if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
     {
         echo '{"query_result":"ERROR"}';
        }
       $fullName = $_GET['fullname'];

       $userName = $_GET['username'];
        $sess = $_GET['user'];
       $fid1 = $_GET['fam'];


         $result=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO $sess (Latitude,Longitude) 
        VALUES ('$fullName','$userName')");

    if($result == true) {
   echo '{"query_result":"SUCCESS"}';
    }
      else{
     echo '{"query_result":"FAILURE"}';
   }
mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

My problem is in my PHP file, `$fullname`, `$username` get values. But `$sess`, `$fid1` did not get value. I can't determine what the problem is.

[image: Details table for update]

Comment: Do any of these statements  `String user = arg0[2];
    String fam = arg0[3];` give you anything in android?

Comment: It's just a declaration right??

Comment: yeah. but does the variable `user` in android give a value when you log it ?

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: yes yes....session created in another class file...I set the variable in textview...It also displays...Then only i pass in signin method

Comment: Do you really mean to store `$fullName` and `$userName` in the db columns `Latitude` and `Longitude`?? That's a bit odd. You should also use POST instead of GET when you send data to the server that should be stored.

Comment: Yes @MagnusEriksson. I want store $fullName and $userName in $sess table

Comment: I get that, but it's odd to store a users names in columns called `Latitude` and `Longitude`. And what is the variable `$sess` actually set to? Are you sure that column exists in the database? Show us your database tables and their column data types. Also, check your servers error log to see if you get any PHP errors.

Comment: already table created by session username..I pass the user name in variable $sess...I need to store lat and longitude in $sess variable table..

Comment: Are you creating one table per user? Don't! Have one table where you store all user sessions. Also, looking at the code, you're not saving latitude and longitude, you're saving full name as latitude and the user name as longitude. I would rethink this design, or if I misunderstand what you're doing, then you need to explain it better.

Comment: ok...If i am using update query,then i also displays same...Query is $sql =mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE details SET lat = '$fullName' , lon='$userName' WHERE fid='$fid1' AND user='$sess'");I attach my snap to question

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.